# speed up file transfers from one machine to other machine

Tags: linux, bash, file-transfer, scp, gnu-parallel

I have to copy around 25 files from one machine to other machine. Each file size is around 15 GB. I have 1GB link and both of these machines are very powerful box. They have around 40 CPUS. Now to copy all those files, it takes 50 minutes for me.

Below is my script which I am running on a box where I am supposed to copy files. It copies 15 files in `/data01/test_primary` folder and other 10 files it copies in `/data02/test_secondary`. Logic is very simple, I figure out which local machine to copy data from and if that local machine is down then I go to remote machine and copy the data.

```
export PRIMARY=/data01/test_primary
export SECONDARY=/data02/test_secondary
export dir3=/bat/data/snapshot/20180227
PRIMARY_FILES=(685 959 682 679 688 651 909 906 657 881 884 878 853 707 847)
SECONDARY_FILES=(950 883 887 890 1001 994 997 1058 981 833)

export LOCATION_1="machineA"
export LOCATION_2="machineB"
export LOCATION_3="machineC"

do_Copy() {
  el=$1
  PRIMSEC=$2
  scp golden@"$LOCATION_1":"$dir3"/proc_"$el"_5.data "$PRIMSEC"/. || scp golden@"$LOCATION_2":"$dir3"/proc_"$el"_5.data "$PRIMSEC"/. || scp golden@"$LOCATION_3":"$dir3"/proc_"$el"_5.data "$PRIMSEC"/. || exit 1
}
export -f do_Copy
parallel -j 5 do_Copy {} $PRIMARY ::: ${PRIMARY_FILES[@]} &
parallel -j 5 do_Copy {} $SECONDARY ::: ${SECONDARY_FILES[@]} &
wait

echo "All copied."
```

---

I believe the main problem with my script is that I might be opening a separate scp connection for each file, that adds a lot of needless overhead. Is there anything I can optimize here? So I am thinking there might be some improvement I can make here so that it can copy fast. As of now I am combining scp with gnu-parallel so that I can achieve parallelism.

What are the options I have to speed things up? I am ready to try out different things and see if it is helping me out or not.

Comment: I guess the connection overhead is negligible versus the transfer time for a 15GB file. I would try disabling encryption or using *arcfour* or *blowfish* if that is appropriate to your environment.

Comment: On a 1Gb/s link, each GB will take at least 8s, so a 15GB file will take 2 minutes and 25 such files will take 50 minutes so you are saturating your network bandwidth. If they are powerful machines, it will be worth the time to compress the data to get it through your narrow pipe as @GonzaloMatheu suggests. Best bet would be to buy a couple of $15 Gigabit Ethernet adaptors...

Comment: I am copying memory mapped file so will see whether compression will help me or not. In the past I did similar test with compression enabled but it didn't help me at all.. Also how can I disable encryption here? I did one more test using `tar` and `nc` as stated [here](https://www.tecmint.com/transfer-files-between-two-linux-machines/) and looks like one file transfer using this approaach was faster than if I compare with `scp` or `rsync`. Not sure why though..

Comment: Using `tar` is unlikely to make a difference - that is only for thousands of small files. Basically, your pipe is 100% full for the entire 50 minutes so the physics are against you. You only have 2 options. 1) Buy a fatter pipe i.e. 10GbE, or more pipes i.e. 2 times 1GbE. Or 2) reduce the volume of data by compression or smarter algorithm i.e. `rsync`  if only part of the data has changed.

Comment: I will try to use compression to see if it helps me out or not. In my case I am copying all new files from scratch.

Comment: Please measure, so we can identify the bottleneck. Use a tool like `iftop` to tell you if you are saturating the link. Use a tool like `iostat -dkx 1` to see if the disks are saturated with I/O.

Answer (score 1):

Enabling **scp** (-C flag) compression might speed things up (depending on data). Having in mind, that you have a lots of CPUs should not take long to compress.

Or, another alternative, if possible, would be to use **[rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)** (-z enables compression) instead of scp. rsync adds a few optimizations to make the operation faster and also has a special delta transfer algorithm (in case of updatng files)

Comment: I have a memory mapped files that I am copying. Do you think compression will helped here? I tried copying one file using `scp` vs `rsync` and I noticed scp was faster somehow? Not sure why.. In my case, we are not updating anything.. Just copying fresh new files again..

Answer (score 0):

> I have to copy around 25 files from one machine to other machine.

`rsync` is good when you only copy differences. From your description it sounds as if the files are new files, and not just updates of existing files.

Do the new files look similar to existing files? In that case you could do:

```
receiver$ cp existing new
receiver$ rsync sender:new new
```